# Сформировать SQL запрос для обновления ячейки с 2 условиями

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, update

Имеем PDO MySQL. Нужно обновить ячейку определенной строки таблицы. 2 условия:

1. user_id равное нужному id
2. language не должно быть равно уже имеющемуся в таблице значению

Использую такой запрос `UPDATE users SET language = :language WHERE user_id = :user_id AND language != :language LIMIT 1` Выводит ошибку, как правильно записать условие, что бы запрос менял значение ячейки,  только в том случае, если они разные.

Ошибка: `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number in`

Comment: Ошибку угадать надо или вы текст ошибки можете показать?

Comment: Также __нельзя__ использовать плейсхолдеры с одинаковым именем.

Comment: На вопрос ответить невозможно, потому что вы привели только текст запроса. А ошибка гласит, что вы передали неправильное количество параметров в PDO функцию, вызов которой и параметры не показали

Comment: @Mike остальное не имеет ни какого значения, сам код верный, как и запрос работает, до тех пор пока не добавляешь к нему условие неравенства.

Comment: @u_mulder и как выйти из этой ситуации?

Comment: __Переименовать__ один из плейсхолдеров.

Comment: Это кстати порекомендовали бы в первом результате поиска по тексту ошибки.

Comment: @u_mulder ошибка пропала, но конечно странно и не логично почему нельзя использовать одинаковые названия, если там одно и тоже значение ведь передается.

Comment: @u_mulder можно еще вопрос, что дописать в запрос, что бы выражение выдавало например FALSE после исполнения запроса, так то execute() выдает TRUE ведь запрос выполняется верно, но как то необходимо отлавливать, что не нужно было менять значение, потому что оно было равно тому что было.

Comment: *почему нельзя использовать одинаковые названия, если там одно и тоже значение ведь передается.* В документации такая возможность описана? нет? значит, использовать нельзя. Ибо то, что не описано явно, может делаться как угодно. Навскидку есть два варианта - заменяются все плейсы, заменяется случайный (как вариант - только первый) плейс. В этом случае надежда на то, что оно будет как-то определённо - это пляска на граблях... тем более надежда на то, что в будущих версиях будет так же.

Comment: А теперь вопрос - а какой смысл делать такую проверку в запросе? Оно типа быстрее должно работать (если да, то хотелось бы каких-то пруфов)? или в таблице есть триггер на update?

Comment: @АлександрБелинский у меня нет таких сложных вещей как триггеры, насчет того быстрее ли, не знаю, но как по мне всегда будет быстрее работать запрос, чем в начале выводить данные, а потом делать их проверку отдельно. Конечно в контексте моей задачи, невозможно увидеть прирост производительности, тут больше культура написания кода. Профессиональным программистом не являюсь, поэтому как там сейчас принято писать такие вещи я не знаю.